# Can you make money from your settlements?

Tags: fallout-4

I know that building the shops in your settlements allow you to sell items and are convenient, but do they allow you to make money?

Do I need to take a certain perk before I can start making money?

Can I make money only with certain shops?

Do I have to invest in them before I make money?

If I CAN make money from them, how do I collect it?

Is it automatic every time I visit the settlement with the shops in them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you need a special perk, [Local Leader level 2](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Local_Leader), as [told here](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/fallout-4-settlement-guide-base-building-materials-settlers/) and build stalls.

Local leader perk level 2 requires and gives :

> 2  CH 6, LVL 14    You can build stores and workstations at workshop settlements.

How you generate income :

> Q: How do you earn money from your Settlements?
>
> A: Learn Local Leader perk and then construct the different stalls in the Stores section

You got to collect the money from the settlement workshop, [confirmed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sernk/dumb_question_how_do_you_collect_money_from/) :

> Go to workstation storage and scroll to misc. You should see caps there when you get paid out

and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sb17h/how_do_settlement_shops_work/) :

> I just checked my workshop. if you hit transfer then scroll to misc there should be bottlecaps in there. I just found 50. you might have to wait a bit longer though

and also [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72807497)

> You were answered, it does indeed go into that settlement's workbench

Comment: Just to be specific you need the level 2 perk as the level one perk only lets you set up supply routes

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the most effective way to make money is to build as many industrial water purifiers as you can, returning regularly to empty the bottles and sell them. Sanctuary is a good place to do this, and with a dozen water purifiers I never had to worry about money again.

You will likely need to build lots of turrets at the settlement, as the purifiers will attract raiders.